# How to write this kind of mongo aggregation match condition in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mongotemplate

My mongo aggregation query is like this:

```
db.events.aggregate({
    "$match" : { $or : [ 
             {"event_state" : "live"},
             {
                 $and: [
                    {"event_state" : "scheduled"},
                    {"schedule.start_time" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2016-12-15T14:06:00.000Z")}}
                    ]
             }
            ] 
        } }, 
        { "$sort" : { "schedule.start_time" : 1}} , 
        { "$project" : { 
            "registered_users_count" : { "$size" : [ "$registered_users"]} , 
            "event_image" : 1 , "celebrity" : 1 , "name" : 1 , "category" : 1 , 
            "schedule" : 1 , "online_moderator" : 1 , "offline_moderator" : 1 , 
            "region" : 1 , "status" : 1 , "event_state" : 1 , "recorder_id" : 1 , 
            "webcast_url" : 1 , "replay_url" : 1
        }})
```

I tried something like below

Variant 1:

```
matchCondition = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("event_state")
                    .is("scheduled").and("schedule.end_time").gt(d)
                    .orOperator(Criteria.where("event_state").is("live")));
```

Variant 2:

```
matchCondition = Aggregation.match(Criteria
                    .where("event_state")
                    .is("live")
                    .orOperator(
                            Criteria.where("event_state").is("scheduled")
                                    .and("schedule.end_time").gt(d)));
```

Sort and Projection Conditions

```
sortCondition = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.ASC,
                    "schedule.start_time");

AggregationOperation projectValues = Aggregation.project()
                .and("registered_users").size().as("registered_users_count")
                .and("event_image").as("event_image").and("celebrity")
                .as("celebrity").and("name").as("name").and("category")
                .as("category").and("schedule").as("schedule")
                .and("online_moderator").as("online_moderator")
                .and("offline_moderator").as("offline_moderator").and("region")
                .as("region").and("status").as("status").and("event_state")
                .as("event_state").and("recorder_id").as("recorder_id")
                .and("webcast_url").as("webcast_url").and("replay_url")
                .as("replay_url");

Aggregation aggrigation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchCondition,
                sortCondition, projectValues);
```

None of the Variant 1 and Variant 2 are producing desired condition. So how to achieve this?

Comment: Try this. OrOperator has to come first.
Aggregation.match(Criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("event_state")
                    .is("scheduled").and("schedule.start_time").gt(d), Criteria.where("event_state").is("live")))

Comment: "Criteria.orOperator" is not working as mentioned above. Because after criteria either you can write "where" or "class". Event if I tried to write the same. It shows me the following " Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method orOperator(Criteria...) from the type Criteria ".

Comment: Sorry for that. Use 'new' operator.Aggregation.match(new Criteria().orOperator(criteria1, criteria2))

Comment: Thank you very much @Lipu. Please put your suggestion as answer. So I can accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Form the spring-data-mongo [API documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#orOperator-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria...-) Criteria.OrOperators take multiple Criteria as argument to form a or operation like.
So the solution for this would be as follows:

```
Aggregation.match(
    new Criteria().orOperator(
        Criteria.where("event_‌​state").is("scheduled").and("schedule.start_time").gt(d),
        Criteria.where("event_state").is("live")
    )
)
```